# I want to delete the string pattern contains in 'var' variable in the log file using sed in Bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, sed

say the file 'log' contains below
a/b/c/d
a/c/d/e
x/x/x/x
e/w/w/s
a

and variable 'var'is as below
set var = "a/b/c/d"

I want to delete 'a/b/c/d' section from log file and only that using pattern in'var'

My Linux command is below:

```
sed -e "/$var/d" -i log
```

The difference is I used a variable as a pattern, while there's forward slashes.
And that's my main requirement.

above command doesn't work

Please can anyone give an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a character that doesn't appear in your pattern, and use that for a command separator. E.g.:

```
sed -e "s_${var}__g" -i log
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes

```
sed -e "s/$var//g"
```